# MEEP FDTD libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate

Tags: python, anaconda, elementary-os, meep

I have a fresh install of [MEEP](https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (the FDTD package) in a Conda environment, on a fresh install of *elementaryOS*. I'm attempting to run the "Visualizing 3D Structures" example code found [here](https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python_Tutorials/Basics/#visualizing-3d-structures). I've installed both both `pymeep` and `pymeep-extras`, as well as `scikit-image` and `vispy` (dependencies for the example code).

Running `python3 visualizing_3d_structures.py` within the Conda environment yields the error `libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate`, and no graphical display appears. A simple Google search reveals a number of StackExchange posts (with various, at times contradictory advice) relating to a similar issue specific to `Raspbian`. none of which seems relevant here, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you also install `mayavi`?

Comment: On a fresh install, maybe consider Mambaforge next time. You're using a package that assumes `conda-forge` is the preferred channel, so Anaconda/Miniconda installations are not as optimal, as a Miniforge variant. And Mamba is a faster interface for Conda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if there isn't a backend (software graphic device) installed in the environment, but there is a libEGL installed at the system-level (EGL is one of the backends for which MEEP will search).

The recommended backend for MEEP is PyQt, so installing that should be sufficient get it working:

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge pyqt
```

That works for me. However, the tutorial directly recommends `mayavi`. This will also install `pyqt`, but obviously has extra stuff as well. So, if you want to strictly follow the tutorial, then run

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge mayavi
```

I verified that also gets it working.